# Using MATLAB to simulate the Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, software, ising-model

I am using MATLAB to simulate a 1D Ising Chain. I am running into an issue where when trying to find heat capacity, my system has a tremendous amount of noise. I'll post my code and an image of the heat capacity (as well as it smoothed 1000 times).

I have tried to smooth the energies first, I've tried having the "equilibrium energy" be the average of the last 5, 10, 100, 1000 timesteps (runs in the code), and nothing has worked. The max should be around 450, but smoothing will change the values.

My heat capacity definition is
$$C = \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial T}$$
But I have also tried using this definition to no avail:
$$C = kT \sigma_E^2$$

Any advice is welcome.

```
%% changeTempIsing1D.m is a script designed to simluate a 1d Ising Chain at different temperatures.
% The Metropolis Algorithm will be used

% function [C, E] = changeTempIsing1D
%% Initializing the chain and other constants
N = 1000; % Number of spins
temporary = rand(1,N); % Building my chain of spins randomly
ups = temporary > .5; % Up spins
downs = -(temporary < .5); % Down spins
chain = ups + downs;
J = 1;
k = 1;
H = 1; % This is the notation for an array [0, .01, .02, ..., .99, 1]
T = linspace(.1,10,100); % T=25*H seems to be a high enough temp
flip = -1; % If I want to flip a spin, I'll multiply it by this.

%% Applying Metropolis Algorithm
time = 30*N; % Number of times I run the algorithm / mcs / Monte Carlo Steps
E = zeros(length(T),time); % A vector consisting of energy of system at different points in algorithm.
site = 1:(N-1);
E(:, 1) = -J.*sum(chain(site).*chain(site+1)) - H.*(sum(chain(site)) + chain(end)); % Initialize energy
for Tindex = 1:length(T)
    chain = ups + downs;
    for run = 2:time
        randSpin = randi(N); % A single randomly chosen spin.
        dE = calc_dE(N, J, chain, H, randSpin); % Change in energy if spin is flipped
        if ( dE < 0 )
            E(Tindex, run) = E(Tindex, run-1) + dE; % Update Energy.
            chain(randSpin) = flip*chain(randSpin); % Flip the spin for good.
        else
            p = exp(-dE/(k*T(Tindex)));
            if (rand <= p) % Accept the change
                E(Tindex, run) = E(Tindex, run-1) + dE;
                chain(randSpin) = flip*chain(randSpin);
            else % Reject the change
                E(Tindex, run) = E(Tindex, run-1);
            end
        end
    end
end

%% Calculate and plot C
% E(:,end) = smooth(E(:,end));
C = diff(E(:,end))./diff(T)';
figure('Color', 'w'); 
% plot(smooth(C(1:end-1), 1000)); % The random energies at high temps make this very noisy. Smooth reduces noise via moving average.
plot(C(1:end-1));
title('Heat Capacity [C] vs Temperature [T]');
xlabel('T');
ylabel('C');

% end
%% Function that calculates change in energy if we were to flip a random spin.
function dE = calc_dE(N, J, chain, H, randSpin)

if randSpin == 1
    dE = 2*J*chain(randSpin)*chain(randSpin+1) + 2*H*chain(randSpin);
elseif randSpin == N
    dE = 2*J*chain(randSpin-1)*chain(randSpin) + 2*H*chain(randSpin);
else
    dE = 2*J*chain(randSpin)*(chain(randSpin-1) + chain(randSpin+1)) +  + 2*H*chain(randSpin);
end

end
```

### Not Smoothed

[image]

### Smoothed

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about debugging code rather than asking about understanding a physics concept.

Comment: [scicomp.se] might be better suited; [so] could also be an alternative, though probably not as ideal as CompSci

Comment: @AaronStevens A fair point that it is regarding debugging code. However, the code uses the Metropolis Algorithm to determine the manner in which the system reaches equilibrium. I am not sure if this is causing undue noise, or what I should expect from such a simulation method.